# Modernizr + Yepnope + FitText (different font sizes / scaling for different viewports)

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, modernizr, yepnope

Firstly, I am rubbish with JS – a novice.

What I want to do is have different FitText (jquery.fittext.js) scaling for different device widths. So for example:

```
$("#hometitle").fitText(1.1); // for mobile

$("#hometitle").fitText(1.2); // for medium screen

$("#hometitle").fitText(1.2); // for large screen
```

I understand that I can use YepNope like this (at the bottom of my HTML document):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Modernizr.load([
    {
        test: Modernizr.mq('(max-width:600px)'),
        yep: '{js_path}mobile.js'
    }
]);
</script>
```

Then inside mobile.js I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    { 
        $("#hometitle").fitText(1.2);
    }
});
```

I wanted to (desperately!) know [a] Am I getting the code above right?; and [b] How would I add additional tests for the three widths to YepNope code (above).

Sorry again, am useless with JS! And have a project that needs to utilise this ASAP.

(side note: Modernizr is loading in the head, and at the bottom of page before my YepNope code jQuery and fittext are loading in)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To me, it seems that you are in the right Track. Using yepnope.js and modernizr to make polyfills.

There are somethings though you are missing, like checking first if media queries are supported by the browser, and also using the device type in the query. Its also a good idea to specify a range via min-width and max width, because, there is a possibility that if you dont, the test conditions will load multiple javascript files.

As for multiple conditions, you can do something like this,

```
Modernizr.load([

    {
        test: Modernizr.mq("only all"),
        nope: 'testnope.js'// this is to check if media queries are supported at all
    },

    {
        test: Modernizr.mq("only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width:1440px)"),
        yep: 'test3.js'
    },

    {
        test: Modernizr.mq("only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px)"),
        yep: 'test2.js'
    },

    {
        test: Modernizr.mq("only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:767px)"),
        yep: 'test1.js'
    },

    {
        test: Modernizr.mq("only screen and (max-width:479px)"),//smallest screen
        yep: 'test0.js'
    }
]);
```

Hope this helps.